# PHP cURL not counting the view

Tags: php, curl, view

Well, I was practising with cURL extension and I came up with a pastebin hit increaser. Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    $proxy_list = file("proxy.txt");
    $paste = "http://pastebin.com/PMHvNzDH";


    for ($count = 0; $count < 100; $count++)
    {
       $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$paste);
       curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_PROXY , $proxy_list[$count]);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com/");
       $text = curl_exec($curl);
       curl_close($curl);
     }
```

It seems that it is not working with the proxy or without it, the proxy.txt is just a file full of IP:PORT lines. So maybe my code is not even reaching the pastebin website?

Comment: Or maybe pastebin is clever enough to see through this. What exactly is your question and - more importantly - how can we help you?

Comment: page hits are usually incremented though `JS` or an `image` on page load to accurately count the hit, `cURL` will not download or execute these resources and your hit will not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it and it works, just make sure if your proxies have user/password that you set them, and please note that what I have seen so far that it count 1 hit per ip so if you ran out of proxies then you ran out of hits

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "user:pass");
```